# Looking for OpenCV tutorial

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Does anyone know some good easy to learn openCV c/c++ tutorial you can recommend? I tried Google, but I wasn't very satisfied with results.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**OpenCV has recently provided a [list of books they recommend](http://opencv.org/books.html).**

Other interesting materials:

- There's a great introduction to OpenCV at [Gady Agam's introduction to OpenCV](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html).
- [Noah Kuntz OpenCV tutorials](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~nk752/tutorials.html) are OK. It covers image manipulation, data types, image processing, camera stuff and several other topics.
- There's also the official [OpenCV Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html), provided by the OpenCV folks themselves.
- Also you can find some good Opencv C++ Examples [here](http://opencv-tutorials-hub.blogspot.in/) to get started.

Comment: You must know that OpenCV provides an API for C programmers and another with the same features for C++. It's your choice.

Comment: The book covers version 1.X, in version 2.X there are some changes in the API.

Comment: The book also presents some theory snippets, useful for a deeper understanding about what the procedures are doing under the covers.

Comment: A [2nd edition of "Learning OpenCV"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022497.do) is coming and it will contain stuff about OpenCV 2.x, which (I find) is much better structured and a lot easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple tutorial with all necessary knowledge of libraries and data structures.
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: Nothing there. Could you please update the link?

Comment: Itseez no longer exists, not even a zombie web site. They were bought by Intel. https://newsroom.intel.com/editorials/intel-acquires-computer-vision-for-iot-automotive/

Answer (score 1):

Nashruddin's OpenCV tutorials such as eye tracking and beginner tutorials.
http://nashruddin.com/tag/opencv

OpenCV tutorials such as object detection, face recognition and cross-compiling.
http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I like the tutorials on [aishack](http://www.aishack.in/topics/tutorials/)