# How to play a video file from my disk using OpenCV.?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

Please help me in achieving above task.I'm newbie to openCV. I have OpenCV 2.2 installed in my system and using VC++ 2010 Express as IDE. I don't have inbuilt webcam in my laptop...
just i learnt how to load image. I'm very eager to load a video file from my disk(preferably  mp4 , flv format) and wish to play it using openCV.

Comment: If you can edit this question to indicate any attempt on your part, feel free to flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **C** interface of OpenCV (which have worked better for me on Windows boxes), the function to load the video file is `cvCaptureFromAVI()`. After that, you need to use the traditional loop to retrieve frames through`cvQueryFrame()` and then `cvShowImage()` to display them on a window created with `cvNamedWindow()`.

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("video.avi");
if(!capture)
{   
    printf("!!! cvCaptureFromAVI failed (file not found?)\n");
    return -1; 
}   

int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
printf("* FPS: %d\n", fps);

cvNamedWindow("display_video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

IplImage* frame = NULL;
char key = 0;

while (key != 'q')
{   
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!frame)
    {   
        printf("!!! cvQueryFrame failed: no frame\n");
        break;
    }

    cvShowImage("display_video", frame);

    key = cvWaitKey(1000 / fps);
}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
cvDestroyWindow("display_video");
```

[This blog post](http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV) brings a little extra info on the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks alot KarlPhilip,,,, the above code works fine.... I'm new to openCV but would like to know more. Please guide me from where should i start ?? can i get some help files as we use get for MATLAB.. Thanks once again ...

Comment: @mahesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679909/looking-for-opencv-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

*(Hummm... you don't seem to be trying to do something by yourself but anyway)*

From the [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html):

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    //Mat edges;
    namedWindow("frames",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        //ignore below sample, since you only want to play
        //cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        //GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        //Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        //imshow("edges", edges);
        imshow("frames", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

This is the [old way](http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV) using opencv 1.x apis.

Comment: The OP want's to load frames from a video file, not a camera