# OpenCV howto use

Tags: opencv

I want to perform some image processing task but I have no idea about it.
What I want to do is this, I have input as an image and I want to find out objects in image like tree, walls, dustbin etc based on distance. I basically want to identify objects that are on my wat in image.

I found out that opencv can be used for this. Can Someone let me know how and where to begin and what opencv algos will be usefull for me?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for OpenCV tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679909/looking-for-opencv-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [OpenCV Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html), more specifically the [**feature2d module**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d).

There are examples that shows the techniques used to accomplish what you are looking for:

- [Feature Matching with FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher)
- [Features2D + Homography to find a known object](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)
- [Feature Detection with SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html)

There are other resources around the web, you can Google them now that you know what to look for. This guide is very nice and shows how to use SURF to detect objects on images:

- [Complete guide using SURF feature detector](http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=2#.UUsbVRn1cc8)

Comment: Thanks karlphillip :)